# How to have a clean repo, including submodules, after a pull request?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I work on a git submodule **child_repo** located in a parent repo **project_repo** with more submodules. I push changes and open pull requests in **child_repo** and it is the only repo (out of all the submodules) I have visibility of (and write rights), but the compilation process of the whole project includes the other submodules.

What would be the best idea to keep the whole parent repo **project_repo** clean and up to date after the pull request with my changes is accepted?

Currently just cloning the whole **project_repo** every time I need to start working on a new feature, but I do not think this is the smartest/right way.

My guess goes as following:

- first discard all files that were not committed with `git checkout --<file>` or `git clean -xdf`. This is because I often write scripts/stuff that helps me with the task but cannot go to *master*.
- `git pull origin master` in the **project_repo** for updating the references
- `git submodule update --recursive --init` for updating the contents of the submodules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for all the detail Victor!

I'm going to refer to the parent repo as **parent_repo** instead of **project_repo** -

Few questions:

> - first discard all files that were not committed with git checkout -- or git clean -xdf. This is because I often write scripts/stuff that helps me with the task but cannot go to master.

Is it correct you were thinking of doing this in **parent_repo**?

Regardless, I have a pretty good idea of what you want to do.

Assuming the settings for your **child_repo** inside `parent_repo/.gitmodules` have `branch` set to `master`, like we in this example below:

```
[submodule "src/child_repo"]
 path = src/child_repo
 branch = master # or whatever branch your PR's for child_repo get merged into

 # extra (unrelated) notes on other settings here:
 url = ../child.git # if parent url is github.com/company/parent, use a relative url for your child_repo, this can avoid git auth/permission/repo access issues in some ci/cd environments
 fetchRecurseSubmodules = true # hopefully this setting is pointless
 # update = merge # you generally dont want to merge by default
```

After your PR to **child_repo** is merged, you have the right idea, but can be optimized slightly.

Assuming you are doing your development inside `parent_repo/src/child_repo`, just:

```
git status # ensure you have no changes inside your `child_repo`, `git stash --all` if you do have changes.
git checkout master
git pull # now child_repo is on master with latest changes, assuming PR was merged into master
cd ../.. # now you're in `parent_repo` root
git status # clean things up if you need, stash, etc. Note, `git stash` or any other commands besides `git submodule ...` will NOT affect the state of your submodule. So, `git stash --all` should always work here 
git stash --all # Only if you have changes _besides_ your src/child_repo submodule pointer
git checkout master
git pull # optionally, `git pull origin master` if you like being specific
git status # should show something like `src/child_repo`
```

Next we'll run `git diff` but more than likely, you'll see a red commit hash and a green commit hash. In that case, you'll probably want to run `git config --global diff.submodule log`, this was me and my co-worker's preferred default setting. More info here: https://www.jvt.me/posts/2018/05/04/git-submodule-diff-formats/

```
git diff # verify commits that have been merged in are correct, ensure you aren't deleting any commits
git diff --submodule=diff # verify actual code changes are also correct (optional)
```

Assuming you just see a your few green commits' messages being added, you can then proceed to update `parent_repo` to point to the new version of `child_repo`. If you can push directly to master (doubt it) you could just:

```
git add .
git commit -m "your_child_repo_name: Learned to handle `--force` setting"
git push
```

If you don't have permission to push, you'll have to do **ANOTHER** PR for this. More than likely, whoever has access to all the submodules should handle updating parent_repo to point to the new child_repo. It'd be very easy for your lead dev/maintainer, they just run:

```
git submodule update
git add .
git commit -m "update child_repo, child_repo2, child_repo3"
```

And this will essentially run `git pull` inside all the submodules.
They can then see your new commits that merged merged by running `git diff --submodule=log` - of course, I'm assuming this lead dev person has permission to push directly to master

Comment: Thanks for the Answer @Devin! I get the overall process you outlined, I appreciate the detail too.

Comment: pretty useful link about diff too! I forgot to state there is a someone who is in charge of the PRs in *parent_repo*, so that part will be fine. Just want to ask a few things regarding your answer, if there is more nested stuff inside any of the other submodules I should go with the `--recursive` flag, right? Also, in case I just want to start working with the last version of the master in *parent_repo* (whether that has the said PR merged or not), this process would end with `git submodule update`, right?

Comment: Adding `--recursive` never hurts, but if you don't have access to other submodules, I don't think it's necessary. (Definitely check without, git status, then add in --recursive, and see if git status changes.)

Comment: So I'm a little confused by your second question -- tell me if this is right: You want to work off of the latest code in *parent_repo*, regardless of which PR's have been merged. To simply ensure you have the latest version of *parent_repo* - assuming you are master: 1. `git pull` - this will update pointers to submodules, but not submodules themselves. You could now check `git status` to see which commit hash pointers have been updated. If there are other submodule pointers that have changed, you can step 2: `git submodule update --recursive --init`.

Comment: Of course, you can just always run step 2. `git submodule update --recursive --init` if you are not concerned about knowing which submodule pointers have changed. We add `--init` and `--recursive` here because we don't know if the latest code on `parent_repo` `master branch` has added a new submodule, either at the top level or inside another submodule.

Comment: Now regarding the PR bit: if you do `git status` on `parent_repo` `master` before your `git pull` - you may see that your git status shows you are attempting to update the pointer to `child_repo`. If you `git pull` and `parent_repo` has merged your PR to update the pointer to `child_repo`, the `git status` would then become clean, and the most recent commits (git log -2) you should see a commit updating the pointer. ADDITION: If your PR has not been merged, and you do `git submodule update` your `chld_repo` submodule will be in detached HEAD state, `chlid_repo` working directory will be in

Comment: (continuing previous comment) `child_repo` working directory will be in the state it was before you started any of your work on your branch

Comment: Basically this setting: `git config --global diff.submodule log` makes submodules go from completely untenable to absolutely good (imo)

Answer (score 0):

> Next we'll run `git diff` but more than likely, you'll see a red commit hash and a green commit hash.
> In that case, you'll probably want to run `git config --global diff.submodule log`.

In that case, use Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), as "[`git -c diff.submodule=log range-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ecbd60ae9980cb3f30f54270f39b464c1f8b39a2/Documentation/git.txt#L77)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt--cltnamegtltvaluegt))</sup> did not show anything for submodules that changed in the ranges being compared, and "`git -c diff.submodule=diff range-diff`" did not work correctly.

Fix this by including the "`--submodule=short`" output unconditionally to be compared.

See [commit 04b1f1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04b1f1fd9d9faeb90d7bd25d8eb4d3ffbb28b9f1) (06 Jun 2022) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit ecbd60a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecbd60ae9980cb3f30f54270f39b464c1f8b39a2), 13 Jun 2022)</sup>

> ### [`range-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/04b1f1fd9d9faeb90d7bd25d8eb4d3ffbb28b9f1): show submodule changes irrespective of diff.submodule
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> After generating diffs for each range to be compared using a '[`git log`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/04b1f1fd9d9faeb90d7bd25d8eb4d3ffbb28b9f1/Documentation/git-log.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log))</sup> invocation, [`range-diff.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/04b1f1fd9d9faeb90d7bd25d8eb4d3ffbb28b9f1/range-diff.c)::read_patches looks for the "`diff --git`" header in those diffs to recognize the beginning of a new change.
>
> In a project with submodules, and with '`diff.submodule=log`' set in the config, this header is missing for the diff of a changed submodule, so any submodule changes are quietly ignored in the range-diff.
>
> When '`diff.submodule=diff`' is set in the config, the "`diff --git`" header is also missing for the submodule itself, but is shown for submodule content changes, which can easily confuse '[`git range-diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/04b1f1fd9d9faeb90d7bd25d8eb4d3ffbb28b9f1/Documentation/git-range-diff.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-range-diff))</sup> and lead to errors such as:
>
> ```
> error: git apply: bad git-diff - inconsistent old filename on line 1
> error: could not parse git header 'diff --git path/to/submodule/and/some/file/within
> '
> error: could not parse log for '@{u}..@{1}'
> ```
>
> Force the submodule diff format to its default ("short") when invoking '`git log`' to generate the patches for each range, such that submodule changes are always detected.
>
> Add a test, including an invocation with '`--creation-factor=100`' to force the second commit in the range not to be considered a complete rewrite, in order to verify we do indeed get the "`short`" format.